# Do async calls within a reliable actor break turn based concurrency?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have the following method in a service fabric reliable actor:

```
async Task IRoomActor.ReportUpdateAsync(SensorCacheItem sensorItem, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            //get the state of this room
            RoomState roomState = await GetOrCreateState(sensorItem.RoomId, cancellationToken);

            //update state based on the sensor cache item passed in
            var existingItem = roomState.Sensors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SensorRowId == sensorItem.SensorRowId);
            if (existingItem != null)
            {
                roomState.Sensors.Remove(existingItem);
            }

            roomState.Sensors.Add(sensorItem);               

            //update status based on sensors
            ResolveStatusFromSensors(roomState, sensorItem);

            //save or update the state
            await StateManager.AddOrUpdateStateAsync(ServiceConstants.RoomActorStateName, roomState,
                (key, value) => roomState, cancellationToken);

            await SaveStateAsync();

            //send updates to Floor Actor          
            await PropagateStateToParent(roomState, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, $"Exception thrown in RoomActor.ReportUpdateAsync(): {e.StackTrace}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Will the awaited calls in this method break the reliable actor's turn based concurrency?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will have no impact on the turn based concurrency as the entire Task returned from ReportUpdateAsync (including it's inner awaits) must complete before the next call is allowed in.

Comment: Great!  Thanks much